# How to access global temp view in another pyspark application?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark shell which invokes pyscript and has created a global temp view

## This is what I am doing in first spark shell script

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Spark SQL Parllel load example") \
.config("spark.jars","/u/user/graghav6/sqljdbc4.jar") \
.config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true") \
.config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled","true") \
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
.config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","50") \
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://xxxxx:9083") \
.config("spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin","true") \
.config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1") \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()

#after doing some transformation I am trying to create a global temp view of dataframe as:

df1.createGlobalTempView("df1_global_view")
spark.stop()
exit()
```

## This is my second spark shell script:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Spark SQL Parllel load example") \
.config("spark.jars","/u/user/graghav6/sqljdbc4.jar") \
.config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true") \
.config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled","true") \
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
.config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","50") \
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://xxxx:9083") \
.config("spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin","true") \
.config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1") \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()

newSparkSession = spark.newSession()
#reading dta from the global temp view
data_df_save = newSparkSession.sql(""" select * from global_temp.df1_global_view""")
data_df_save.show()

newSparkSession.close()
exit()
```

I am getting below error:

```
Stdoutput pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Table or view not found: `global_temp`.`df1_global_view`; line 1 pos 15;\n'Project [*]\n+- 'UnresolvedRelation `global_temp`.`df1_global_view`\n"
```

Looks like I am missing something. How can I shared the same global temp view across multiple sessions? 
Am I closing the spark session incorrectly in first spark shell?
I have found couple of answers already on stack-overflow but was not able to figure out the cause.

Comment: Ok.  It will be accessible in different Spark session in same pyscript  and cannot be accessed if I start new shell to execute my another pyscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `createGlobalTempView` so it's a temporary view and won't be available after you close the app.

In other words, it will be available in another `SparkSession`, but not in another PySpark application.

Comment: Ok got it.. I can run multiple pyscript using one Spark submit and then can create multiple session among different pyscript and can have access to global temp view also if it was created in earlier pyscript within the same application..

Comment: You are right.. simple example http://www.balakumarp.net/2019/01/29/pyspark-sharing-spark-context-and-spark-session-across/