# Pyspark, how often should I create new Spark session?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have pipeline which looks like class with some methods. In each method I process some data. Example:

```
class Pipeline:

    def load_users(self):
        pass

    def load_sessions(self):
        pass
```

Should I initialize new spark session in every method with custom config? Or better to initialize its once in `__init__` method?

Comment: The question does not just apply to pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can live with doing this once up front and changing Spark properties as you go through your various Actions / Pipelines, using spark.conf.set("prop", 'val'). That is how most do and it there are few examples to be found to the contrary.

If you want better insight, then from the master himself: [How many SparkSessions can a single application have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723761/how-many-sparksessions-can-a-single-application-have). This adds some insights which one could consider in relation to your question. Question is if you really need to consider this.